# Can I define the Tauri app URL at runtime

Tags: tauri

From what I understand, each Tauri app includes a tauri.conf.json file that defines the app URL.
tauri.conf.json

Is the another way to define the URL at runtime? E.g. to receive the url via args and open the window accordingly (or does Tauri force user to compile the app with the URL?)

{
"build": {
"beforeBuildCommand": "npm run build",
"beforeDevCommand": "npm run dev",
"devPath": http://localhost:3000,
"distDir": "../build",
"withGlobalTauri": true
},

Comment: That's the thing, You have to use a wildcard '*' which allows all  URL's . You're basically opting out of it.